# Every group of order 111 is cyclic. (True or False)

Tags: group-theory

By Lagrange's theorem the possible order of the subgroups of the group will be 1 or 3 or 37 or 111

Now by Sylow's 1st theorem this group must have a subgroup of order 3 and as well as 37.

Then we can prove that every abelian group of order 111 is cyclic.

Now my question is:

Is there be any non-abelian group of order 111?

If there be a non abelian group of order 111 then the given statement is False otherwise the statement is True .

Thanks.

Comment: http://planetmath.org/groupsoforderpq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jungnickel gave a nice result in [On the Uniqueness of the Cyclic Group of Order $n$](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Jungnickel92.pdf) that any group of order $n$ is cyclic iff $(n,\varphi(n))=1$, which addresses this problem quickly.

Since $(111,\varphi(111))=(111,72)=3$, there are noncyclic groups of order $111$. The first paragraph of the above paper shows how to construct a nonabelian group of order $n$, when $(n,\varphi(n))\neq 1$.

Comment: But Z_10 is cyclic although (10,φ(10))≠1....But according to the necessity of your statement (10,φ(10)) must be 1.....@Ben West

Comment: @IndrajitGhosh $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is cyclic for any $n$. If $(n,\varphi(n))=1$, $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is the only group of order $n$. If $(n,\varphi(n))\neq 1$, there is still a cyclic group of order $n$, but there are others as well. For instance, the dihedral group of order $10$ is nonabelian.